# BOM Entry creation fails for XML Schema (Business Rules service on Bluemix)

Tags: ibm-cloud, business-rules, ibm-odm

I am working with the Rule Designer for the Business Rules service on Bluemix to create a BOM entry from an XML schema. When I select the XOM entry in the wizard, I see the error: 
"Invalid XOM entry, please check your log file"

The Eclipse log file contains the following stacktrace:

> !MESSAGE An error occurred while loading the XML schema
>   C:\mySchema.xsd.
>
> !STACK 0
>
> ERROR ERR011: in source file:C:/mySchema.xsd, after line 18, before
>   lines ?, The type reference on MyType cannot be resolved.
>
> ERROR ERR011: in source file:C:/mySchema.xsd, after line 21, before
>   lines ?,
>
> The type reference on MyType cannot be resolved.
>
> ```
>  at ilog.rules.xml.model.IlrXsdXomConvertorBase.convertSchema(IlrXsdXomConvertorBase.java:111)
>
>  at com.ibm.rules.dynamic.xom.SchemaDriver.loadModel(SchemaDriver.java:159)
>
>  at com.ibm.rules.dynamic.xom.XsdBuilder.buildXom(XsdBuilder.java:63)
>
>  at ilog.rules.studio.model.xom.impl.IlrDynamicXOMPathEntryImpl.getXsdReflect(IlrDynamicXOMPathEntryImpl.java:676)
> ```
>
> ...

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had multiple xsd:import statements for the same namespace. 
I put all the declarations for the namespace in a single file, and then used a single xsd:import for that namespace.

Another way is to add a new schema file that uses several xsd:include statements to include all the schema declarations for the namespace into this new file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message when I used www. at my xsd namespace.

Try changing your namespace "schema targetNamespace= and xmlns:tns= schema" until you can create the BOM succesfully. Verify you have the same value for both.